# RewriteRule conflict with folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my page I have a login folder. When I enter into *domain.com/login/* it takes me correctly to the folder. When I write *domain.com/login* it also opens the page but the url changes into *domain.com/login/?cname=login*

My other main link is like *domain.com/company* and works correctly. However if i write *domain.com/company/* it sais object not found.

How can I fix these?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain.com/index.(php|html?)
# domain.com/login
RewriteRule ^/login?$ /domain.com/login/index.php
# domain.com/abc
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)?$ /domain.com/profile/company-profile.php?cname=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sound like you want to have domain.com/login/ or domain.com/login take you to the login folder.
The rule below will ensure that all of your folders end with a trailing slash and thus make domain.com/login work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

The next rule below will allow domain.com/company/ to work. In combination with the rule above, it will also ensure that domain.com/company continues to work.

```
RewriteRule ^company/$ profile/company-profile.php?cname=company [NC,L]
```

You should delete your other rules as they are incorrect.

Edit

Based on your last response modify the last rule to be

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/$ profile/company-profile.php?cname=$1 [NC,L]
```

i.e. for all URI's except login do the rewrite company rule.

Comment: Thank you for this. It really helped me to understand how these works. However the company was just an example, it may be any name. How do I change that ?

Comment: I added this `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/$ /profile/company-profile.php?cname=$1 [NC,L]` instead of what you posted me for the company but it messes with `login`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you understand that any # of RewriteCond's only apply to the very next RewriteRule.  I don't understand why you're matching against REQUEST_URI with a RewriteCond, rather than just matching it as part of the RewriteRule.

I also don't understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish with the `^/login?$` RewriteRule.  I'm guessing the '?' needs to be escaped - otherwise, you're literally asking it to match against "`/login`" or "`/logi`".

Due to complications from the above concerns, I'm guessing your "domain.com/login" request is being handled by the 2nd RewriteRule which contains the "cname=", though I'm confused why you then don't see the "company-profile.php" as well (assuming maybe just an oversight in your question)?

After considering the above and trying to simplify this a little, I'm guessing everything should fall into place.  If not, please comment back, and we'll see what we can do.

Comment: The truth is that I am not very familiar with htaccess and I built that through some readings on the web. It would be great if you should post me the how my code should be.

Comment: Rewrite rules aren't specific to .htaccess, but are part of the larger Apache configuration.  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/ is an excellent guide to these.  Looks like Ulrich has already given you most of what you need.  :-)